# Bugzilla performance slow

Tags: perl, performance, bugzilla

I just install Bugzilla 4.0.1 in Internet Information Server 7.0, Windows 7. Perl is provided by ActivePerl.
When I am opening every page, it will almost cost 3-5 seconds to load a page. It is a empty Bugzilla without any project. And machine load is very low.

I try Internet Explorer 9.0 and Google Chrome. The time to load page is almost same, 3-5 seconds.

How can I config the system to improve the performance of Bugzilla?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bugzilla is coded in Perl, and Perl can be slow for a big-medium web applications in plain CGI - if the perl scripts are to compiled for each request. I had to configure Bugzilla with [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/) in the server to get decent performance. That was a linux box, though - I'm not sure about mod_perl in Windows.

BTW, the client side (your browser) is irrelevant here.